# How to remove query string from "href" attribute of anchor using php?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

i have this string :

```
$string = '<a href="/title/tt3110958/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2" style="color:#666" >';
```

how to remove all word from `?` to `"` in my string .
i try this:

```
$result = preg_replace("/\?.+/", "", $string);
```

but its remove all word after `?` !!!

Comment: There's a bunch of different ways to do this with PHP. What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnConde i update my question !

Comment: Use `/\?[^"]+/` instead.

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks But how can i use `"` inside ?

Comment: I have submitted my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/\?[^\"]+/` like bellow:

```
<?php
$string = '<a href="/title/tt3110958/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2" style="color:#666" >';
$result = preg_replace("/\?[^\"]+/", "", $string);
echo $result;
?>
```

Output : `<a href="/title/tt3110958/" style="color:#666" >`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()` for that

**Example:**

```
$myStr = "foo? bar???";
$myStr = str_replace("?","\"",$myStr);
```

Comment: It doesn't remove query string of url.

Comment: i thinks `$str` is undefined variable.