# How can I strip a href attribute without the query?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using Google Sheets, I'd like to grab a URL without a **possible** query from a "href" attribute. For example, get `https://test.com` from `<a href="https://test.com">Test1</a>` or `<a href="https://test.com?this">Test1</a>`.

I've used the regex answer offered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426187/4829915 to remove the query string, and then extracted the actual URL.

Is there a way to do it in one formula?

Please see below what I did. In all of these examples the final output is `https://test.com`

```
    A                                                           B                               C
1                                                               \?[^\"]+                        href="(.+)"
2   <a href="https://test.com">Test1</a>                        =REGEXREPLACE(A2, B$1, "")      =REGEXEXTRACT(B2, C$1)
3   <a href="https://test.com?param=eter">Test2</a>             =REGEXREPLACE(A3, B$1, "")      =REGEXEXTRACT(B3, C$1)
4   <a href="https://test.com?param=eter&and=this">Test3</a>    =REGEXREPLACE(A4, B$1, "")      =REGEXEXTRACT(B4, C$1)
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could understand about ``one command``, how about this formula? ``=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(http.+?)[\?""]")`` If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: That works, @Tanaike, thanks! I've rephrased the "command" into "formula". Feel free to write it as an answer. I wonder though if there's any solution that doesn't rely on http, as it might be best to try to refrain from hardcoded string regex.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When it uses a custom function using Google Apps Script, I think that [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/) can be used for this situation. But when only formula is used, ``REGEXEXTRACT()`` might be one of better ways. I would like to post an answer including both samples after this. If that is useful, I'm glad.

Comment: I prefer REGEXEXTRACT. Just wished it didn't have to hardcode the word "http" in it.

Comment: I could understand about it, just now. For example, if the position of ``href="###"`` is constant, how about ``=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, """(.+?)[\?""]")``?

Comment: Actually, href="(.+?)[\?"] (I put it in, for example, cell C1) did the trick! Can you update your answer? I think "href" is more reliable than "http".

Comment: I had thought that you don't want to use both ``http`` and ``href=``, because you said ``Just wished it didn't have to hardcode the word "http" in it.``. So as other sample, I proposed above. I apologize for it.

Comment: Nevertheless, you put "http" in the answer" so please change to href="(.+?)[\?"] and I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I added 2 samples. Could you please confirm it? If those didn't work, I apologize again.

Comment: I meant, can you edit your answer and change `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(http.+?)[\?""]")` to `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, C1) where C1 is href="(.+?)[\?"]`?

Comment: I could understand about what you want to do. So I replaced it. Could you please confirm it? I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns. In the 1st pattern, it uses `REGEXEXTRACT`. In the 2nd pattern, it uses a custom function using Google Apps Script (This is a sample.).

#### Pattern 1: Using formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, C1)
```

where C1 is `href="(.+?)[\?"]`

#### Pattern 2: Using custom function

When you use this, please copy and paste the script to the script editor. Then please use it at a cell like `=getUrl(A2)`.

```
function getUrl(value) {
  var obj = XmlService.parse(value.replace(/&/g, ";"));
  var url = obj.getRootElement().getAttribute("href").getValue();
  return url.split("?")[0];
}
```

#### Results:

[image]

#### References:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/)